# ObjectId is not defined while deleting from mongoDb using meanstack

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, mean-stack

I am trying to delete the entry from MOngoDb by using MEAN STACK with ANgular 4.(New to this technology)

typescript:

```
deleteitem(id){
  let deleteresult;
  let itemid = id;
  this.dataService.deleteitem(itemid)
  .subscribe(res =>deleteresult =res,
  err => this.apiError = err,
  )
};
```

dataservice:

```
deleteitem(itemid): Observable<any>{
      let data =new URLSearchParams();
      data.set('deleteId', itemid);
      console.log(data.toString());
      return this.http.post(URL, data.toString())
      .map(res=> res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw('Server Error To delete the item'));
       }
```

Router.js

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID; 
 router.post('/deleteitem', function(req, res){
      MongoClient.connect('URL',function(err, client){
      if (err) throw err;
      var myDB = client.db('DbName');
       var collection = myDB.collection('collectionName');
       console.log(req.body);       
       //var objectId = collection.getObjectId();
       collection.remove({_id: ObjectId(req.body.deleteId), function(err, result)
      {
        res.send((result==1)?{msg:deleted} : {msg:"error:"+ err});
      }});
    })
    })
```

Error:

> ObjectId is not defined.

Also the console.log(req.body) gives a "{}" value. Not sure why.
But console.log(data.toString()); in the dataservice gives the value of intended _id to be removed from MongoDb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `data` instead of `data.toString()` in

```
return this.http.post(URL, data.toString())
```

This will give you output value in console.log(req.body);

Also, try replacing the below line of code

```
collection.remove({_id: ObjectId(req.body.deleteId), function(err, result)
```

with

```
collection.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(req.body.deleteId)}, function(err, result)
```

You need to create a new instance of mongodb here.
Hope this works.